# Laravel Many to Many Relationship to join two models

Tags: php, laravel-5

I struggle to get this right with Laravel 5. However, in Rails, I can easily do this:

A User can be a part many Teams. We know that tables `User` and `Team` could not have a relation id so I wont post those schema here but instead I have a `TeamUser` table:

```
Schema::create('team_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->integer('team_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**TeamUser.php:**

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function team()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}
```

**Team.php**

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, TeamUser::class);
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function teams()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Team::class, TeamUser::class);
}
```

It seems as if laravel's doc and other tutorials I have seen are different. Im new to Laravel, again, and I need this setup.

**Tinker:**

```
$tu = App\TeamUser::create([ 'user_id' => 1, 'team_id' => 1 ]);
```

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException with message 'user_id'

**Expected:**

```
$tu->users // is_array($tu) to be true
```

Could someone please explain what is wrong here? Thanks much.

Comment: What you're looking for is a pivot table. you don't need the `hasManyThrough `, just `hasMany` should be enough. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many should be a good reference point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `hasManyThrough()` only substitutes for chaining 2 `hasMany` relationships. In your case we have to deal with a single [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship, which is defined by using `belongsToMany()` on both models involved.

For that to work you should create a join-table. In Laravel, the naming convention for join tables is the names of both models involved, singular, **snake_cased**, and in alphabetical order, and separated by a `_`. In this case the table name would be `team_user`.

You'll want to create a migration through the artisan CLI:

`$ php artisan make:migration create_team_user_pivot_table`

And put the contents below inside the `up()` and `down()` methods of the new class that was created for you in `YOUR_PROJECT/database/migrations/`.

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('team_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('team_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['team_id', 'user_id']);
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('team_user');
}
```

When all set you can run the new migration with the following console command:
`$ php artisan migrate`

Then, in your `Team` model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

and in your `User` model:

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
}
```

This should be all you need to get the relations working.

Note that nothing stops you from creating an extra model called `TeamUser` to access your pivot/join table directly. You do have to specify the table name in that model to be `team_user`, since Eloquent assumes the table name to be the plural snake-cased version of the model name: `team_users`. This is as easy as:

`protected $table = 'team_user';`

If the sole purpose of the extra table is storing relations, however, I can not see why defining a Model class for that table can be considered useful. Laravel comes with [a bunch of extra features that let you define and access additional columns on join tables through relationships.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

(scroll down a bit to **Saving Additional Data On A Pivot Table**)

Comment: Wealth of information here. I'll have a go and report

Comment: Ok, Ive `$tu = App\TeamUser::create([ 'user_id' => 1, 'team_id' => 1 ]);` then `App\User::find(1)->teams` but getting empty array. I do have a team with an id of 1

Comment: 1. Have you confirmed that the new record was created in `team_user`?
2. If you are testing in `artisan tinker` you might have to refetch the model, or restart tinker entirely.

Comment: I also notice that you are defining the relation through the additional model `TeamUser`. Have you specified the following: 
`protected $table = 'team_user';` 
`protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'team_id'];`

Comment: Yes. What should be in TeamUser.php?

Comment: Both protected properties above should be in TeamUser, to allow you to create the relation as you do in your second comment.

Comment: Correct: public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function team()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
  }

Comment: Should definitely be `belongsToMany`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143887/discussion-between-jeffrey-westerkamp-and-sylar).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement many-to-many relation with middle table by using `belongsToMany`

For example in **Team.php**:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'team_user', 'team_id', 'user_id');
}
```

In that case you don't need to create model **TeamUser**

Answer (score 0):

To avoid seeing the pasted error message you would have to add the following line to your TeamUser.php class:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'team_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do when working out Eloquent relationships is say them out loud:

- A user can be part of many teams
- A team can have many users

This says that you'll need a `many-to-many` relationship. So, what we do in our `User.php`:

```
public function teams() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
}
```

Then, in our `Team.php`, we do this;

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(Users::class);
}
```

This should automatically make a pivot table, and set you up to the point where you could request e.g. a users teams by doing: `Users::find(1)->teams`. *Note that i didn't use parentheses because I want the result, not the query builder object.*

Comment: The thing with this is that Team table could not possible have a `user_id` and its asking for a user id

Comment: The `hasMany` in `Team.php` is wrong. `hasMany` assumes that the foreign key back to the `Team` model lives in the table that represents the model you are trying to define the relationship with, whereas `belongsToMany` WILL assume an additional table exists that defines the relations by matching ID's.